# XCode V6.0.1, compiling for 6 or 6+ gives "Undefined Symbol for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently upgraded to XCode V6.0.1, and when I try to run my app on the iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+ simulator I get several errors of the following type:

"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CATransform3DConcat"

I can run the app on the 4s, 5, and 5s simulators no problem.
 Here is a screen shot of my build settings: 
[image: ScreenShot of Build Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my search paths for Header and Library and removed my 3rd party framework and reinstalled.  I manually set my search paths in Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting "Build Active Architecture only" to "NO"